# How to have stack trace for asynchron error in Jest?

Tags: javascript, promise, jestjs

In Jest, when I use a Promise which rejects, I can't see the stack trace in with my own code...

```
async function throwReject() {
  return Promise.reject("There is an asynchron error")
}

it("should display an asynchron error", async () => {
  await expect(throwReject()).rejects.toBe(1)
})
```

For this test, I have this not very useful message :

```
expect(received).rejects.toBe(expected) // Object.is equality

Expected: 1
Received: "There is an asynchron error"

  12 |
  13 | it("should display an asynchron error", async () => {
> 14 |   await expect(throwReject()).rejects.toBe(1)
     |                                       ^
  15 | })
  16 |

  at Object.toBe (../../node_modules/expect/build/index.js:241:20)
  at _callee$ (unit/promise.spec.js:14:39)
  at tryCatch (../../node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:63:40)
  at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (../../node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:293:22)
  at Generator.next (../../node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:118:21)
  at asyncGeneratorStep (../../node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:3:24)
  at _next (../../node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:25:9)
  at ../../node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:32:7
  at Object.<anonymous> (../../node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:21:12)
```

On the other way, for a synchron error, the stack trace is a lot better, whith the line which has thrown the error :

```
function throwError() {
  throw new Error("There is an error")
}

it("should display error", () => {
  expect(throwError()).toBe(1)
})
```

● should display error

```
There is an error

  1 | function throwError() {
> 2 |   throw new Error("There is an error")
    |         ^
  3 | }
  4 |
  5 | async function throwReject() {

  at throwError (unit/promise.spec.js:2:9)
  at Object.<anonymous> (unit/promise.spec.js:10:10)
```

Do I wrote wrongly my tests ?
Have you some resources to look at ?